# Mosquitto MQTT client certificate exception

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm developing an application that, in summary, uses MQTT to send sensor values to a broker to later visualize that data in a dashboard web application.
I have five microcontrollers connected to the broker and I've set up a server certificate for the broker and client certificates for each microcontroller.

The problem is that, in the mosquitto.conf file I require the use of client certificates for the clients that want to connect, so if I want to subscribe to a topic from my web application I need a client certificate. I'm trying to find the right approach for accomplishing this, but it seems that having a certificate and key in a machine you cannot control is a big security risk.

It would be ideal if someone knew a way of tweaking the mosquitto configuration file or establish some kind of exception (maybe similar to ACL's) to only require client certificates for certain clients (in my case, the microcontrollers) and use username@password for the others (web clients). Is it possible to do such a thing?

Any help would be much appreciated

**EDIT** (regarding @hardillb 's answer)

My mosquitto.conf:

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

per_listener_settings true

listener 9873
protocol websockets
#http_dir /home/jamengual/Desktop/UIB/TFG/mqtt/webAPP
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt

listener 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
require_certificate true
```

The "per_listener_settings true" makes the server go to an active(exited) state.
From the mosquitto.conf guide:

Talking about authentication mechanisms:

> Both certificate and PSK based encryption are configured on a
>   per-listener basis.

Talking about the per_listener_settings options:

```
per_listener_settings [ true | false ]

    If true, then authentication and access control settings will be controlled on a per-listener basis. The following options are affected:

    password_file, acl_file, psk_file, allow_anonymous, allow_zero_length_clientid, auth_plugin, auth_opt_*, auto_id_prefix.
```

So I understand that the per_listener_settings option might not be necessary for the require_certificate part. However, I still need it to configure the usernames and passwords for the websockets.

Is there something wrong with my configuration file?

[Link to my question about how to store client certificates and keys in the client's machine](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/229094/client-certificate-and-key-storage-on-clients-machine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mosquitto allows you to have multiple listeners per broker that all share the same topic space.

Listeners can support native MQTT, MQTT over Websockets (including Websockets over TLS) and MQTT over TLS.

It also has the `per_listener_settings` option which allows you to specify different authentication options for different listeners. This option was added in mosquitto version 1.5.

So in this case, you can create a MQTT over TLS listener and use client certificates to authenticate those users (devices) and a MQTT over Websocket listener that will use username/password authentication.

e.g. something like this (but probably using a authentication plugin rather than acl/password files)

```
per_listener_settings true

listener 1884
cafile /path/to/ca
certfile /path/to/cert
keyfile /path/to/key
require_certificate true
acl_file /path/to/acl_file

listener 8883
protocol websockets
acl_file /path/to/acl_file
password_file /path/to/password
```

You can also include the `ca_file`, `cert_file` and `key_file` options for the websocket listener, to enable Websockets over TLS (but don't use the `require_certificate` because browser side client certificate handling for websockets is not a great experience, as they don't ask which to use). But normally I would normally use something like NGINX to proxy for the websocket listener and also do the TLS termination.

Details of all the options can be found in the mosquitto.conf man page: https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html

Comment: thanks for the answer. Having the per_listener_settings options makes the server crash and go to an active(exited) state.  However, if I put require_certificate true , the websockets listener seems to ignore it and lets clients connect. I will edit my question to include my mosquitto.conf file. Also, the link to the mosquitto.conf guide says: "Both certificate and PSK based encryption are configured on a per-listener basis.", so I understand it might not be necessary to include the per_listener_settings true option.

Comment: What version of mosquitto are you running? Also check the logs as to WHY it crashed ( I will guess it's because you are running an old version)

Comment: Also as I said, you should not be using client side certificates (`require_certificate true`) with websockets as the browsers don't properly support selecting the right certificate to send.

Comment: I'm running mosquitto version 1.4.15. Maybe I didn't explain myself well. I meant that even if I put the require_certificate true (without per_listener_settings), the websockets is not affected, and that's what I want, because my plan is to use username and password for the websockets listener and TLS for the other. The logs are not reporting anything regarding configuration errors, but I'm gonna take a look again. Please look at my edit to the question. Thanks!

Comment: DO NOT USE `require_certificate true` if you want to use username and password for websockets

Comment: don't I still need to include that if I want client certificate for the microcontrollers?

Comment: only in the listener for the native MQTT TLS listener

Comment: okay thank you, that's what I have right now, but as I want to use usernames and passwords for the web client, I still need the `per_listener_settings true` option. As I said, it makes the server crash, but I'm going to take a deeper look on that.

Comment: You need at least version 1.5.x for the `per_listener_settings` flag (upgrade to 1.6.x)

Comment: just updated to mosquitto 1.6.8 and it seems to work now. Thank you for your time and help! @hardillb